# ifram only takes a part of body on safari on ipad when orientation is changed

Tags: ipad, iframe, safari, height, screen-orientation

I am loading a browser with a iframe in safari on ipad. I have body of the page loaded in iframe set as width:100% & height:100%. When I load the page in the iframe, it looks good, but when I rotate the ipad from landscape to portrait, then I see that iframe only takes a part of the page (height now is width of landscape mode earlier).Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the `height:100%, width:100%, padding:0px, and margin:0px` for the body of the page containing the iframe and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes `frameborder="0" allowfullscreen`

http://jsfiddle.net/masau/7wrhm/

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned, but it seems to be not working for my scenario. Thanks though.